# Possible to get documentation for model properties in django.contrib.admindocs?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to have model properties (like the following) show up in the admin documentation using `django.contrib.admindocs`?

```
  class MyModel(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      date_approved = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

      @property
      def status(self):
      """
        returns the status of object
      """
      if self.date_approved and self.public:
        return "Public"
      elif self.public:
        return "Pending Approval"
      else:
        return "Private"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found is to monkey-patch `admindocs`.

In file `django/contrib/admindocs/views.py` find the method `ModelDetailView.get_context_data`. There is a section that gathers model methods, but skips the properties as they are not methods. So we need to (1) add properties to the condition and (2) append the property to the list of fields.

```
# Gather model methods.
for func_name, func in model.__dict__.items():
    #
    # CHANGE 1: add isinstance(func, property) to the condition
    #
    # if inspect.isfunction(func): # old line
    if inspect.isfunction(func) or isinstance(func, property):
        try:
            for exclude in MODEL_METHODS_EXCLUDE:
                if func_name.startswith(exclude):
                    raise StopIteration
        except StopIteration:
            continue
        verbose = func.__doc__
        if verbose:
            verbose = utils.parse_rst(utils.trim_docstring(verbose), 'model', _('model:') + opts.model_name)

        #
        # CHANGE 2: If this is a property, show it as a 'field'
        #
        if isinstance(func, property):
            fields.append({
                'name': func_name,
                'data_type': get_return_data_type(func_name),
                'verbose': verbose or '',
            })
        # Else if a method has no arguments, show it as a 'field', otherwise
        # as a 'method with arguments'.
        elif func_has_no_args(func) and not func_accepts_kwargs(func) and not func_accepts_var_args(func):
            fields.append({
                'name': func_name,
                'data_type': get_return_data_type(func_name),
                'verbose': verbose or '',
            })
        else:
            arguments = get_func_full_args(func)
            # Join arguments with ', ' and in case of default value,
            # join it with '='. Use repr() so that strings will be
            # correctly displayed.
            print_arguments = ', '.join([
                '='.join(list(arg_el[:1]) + [repr(el) for el in arg_el[1:]])
                for arg_el in arguments
            ])
            methods.append({
                'name': func_name,
                'arguments': print_arguments,
                'verbose': verbose or '',
            })
```